# viewbox works in chrome and firefox but not in phantomjs

Tags: html, svg, phantomjs

I have a web app that displays an SVG timeline.  The SVG is using a ViewBox to properly scale the timeline as the browser page grows/shrinks.

The SVG timeline properly appears in firefox/chrome etc.  It also properly appears in chrome when I print to pdf straight from chrome.

WORKS IN FIREFOX AND CHROME BUT NOT IN PHANTOMJS...

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: 0px;" data-hasqtip="26" viewBox="0 0 1138 130" aria-describedby="qtip-26">
```

When I print to pdf using phantomjs however, the SVG timeline does not appear at all.  If instead of using a viewBox, I use fixed width and height for the SVG timeline, it does properly show up in the phantomjs pdf.

WORKS IN PHANTOMJS...

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: 0px;" data-hasqtip="26" width="1100" height="900" aria-describedby="qtip-26">
```

Does anyone have any insight/heads up in terms of why this is occurring?  Have stackoverflowed, googled the issue but nothing specific

Thanks in advance for any help

David

ccprog,
per your kind request, below is the enclosing html etc.  viewBox="0 0 718 130" below works in chrome/FF, does not work in phantomjs

Thanks fot any heads up/help in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]--><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide{display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-block-transitions{transition:0s all!important;-webkit-transition:0s all!important;}.ng-hide-add-active,.ng-hide-remove{display:block!important;}</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Objective Arts</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- iOS -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="public/images/logo-white.png">
    <!--<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <!-- Android -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="images/logo-white.png">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-motion/dist/angular-motion.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/css/xeditable.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-additions/dist/bootstrap-additions.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-growl-v2/build/angular-growl.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/c3/c3.css">
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/cfsPrint.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/assessmentNavigator.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/assessmentValidations.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/plan.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/abn_tree.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/flags.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/chronoline.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/qtip2/jquery.qtip.min.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->



<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body ng-app="oaClientJs" style="" class="ng-scope">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a>
    to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->



<div full-screen-loader="" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div id="fullscreenloaderoverlay" style="zoom: 1;" ng-show="visible" class="ng-hide">
</div>
<div id="fullscreenloadermessage" class="panel panel-default ng-hide" ng-show="visible">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="text-centered">
            <h5 class="ng-binding">Loading Form<img src="images/loader.gif"></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>



<div growl="" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="growl-container growl-fixed top-right" ng-class="wrapperClasses()"><!-- ngRepeat: message in growlMessages.directives[referenceId].messages --></div></div>

<!-- AngularJS controlled views -->
<div class="container fill">
    <!-- ngView:  --><div ng-view="" class="fill ng-scope"><style xmlns:page-break-inside="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ng-scope">

    .narrative {
        zoom: 0.8;
    }

    .nopadding {
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }

    .strength {
        background-color: #a0b2be !important;
        border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }

    .three {
        background-color: #be969c !important;
        border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }

    .two {
        background-color: #fae190 !important;
        border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }

    .one {
        background-color: #7abe77 !important;
        border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }

    .note {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .date {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 10px;
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        align-content: center;
    }

    .unbreakable {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .centered {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .sphere {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .printOnly{
        display:none;
    }

    @media print {
        html {
            zoom: .7;
        }
        .printOnly{
            display:block;
        }
    }
    
</style>

<!-- <test> start of form panel -->
<div id="detailHideContent" class="row hidden-print ng-scope">
<div id="realContent" class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <b class="ng-binding">Form - ....</b>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>...:</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 ng-binding">ID10006</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>....:</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 ng-binding">....</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>...</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a ng-href="#/clientTab/10006" class="ng-binding" href="#/clientTab/10006">....</a></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>...</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 ng-binding">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row top-buffer">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>...</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 ng-binding">12</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>...</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- ngIf: !isEditMode --><span ng-if="!isEditMode" class="ng-binding ng-scope">...</span><!-- end ngIf: !isEditMode -->
                <!-- ngIf: isEditMode -->
                <!-- ngIf: isEditMode -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>Org Unit:</b></div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-6">
                <span ng-show="isEditMode &amp;&amp; availableOus.length == 0" class="ng-hide">No placements exist for the specified time range</span>
                <span ng-show="!isEditMode || availableOus.length == 1" class="ng-binding">WEFC - EIIS (36EWEI)</span>
                <select ng-show="isEditMode &amp;&amp; availableOus.length &gt; 1" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-hide" ng-options="placement.nameCode for placement in availableOus track by placement.id" ng-model="selected.orgUnit"><option value="140" selected="selected">...</option></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row ng-hide" ng-show="isEditMode &amp;&amp; regenerateRequired()">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-6">
                <span>Regenration is required</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>  <!-- end <div id="detailHideContent" class="row hidden-print"> -->
<!-- END OF FORM PANEL -->





<!-- START OF COURSE OF CARE PANEL -->
<div id="detailHideContent" class="row ng-scope">
<div id="formDetails" class="panel panel-default" ng-show="showDetails()">
    <div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon"></span> <b>...</b>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="timeline-tgt ng-isolate-scope" reactive-chrono-line=""
chrono-data="chronoline"><div class="chronoline-wrapper 
chronoline-draggable"><div class="chronoline-canvas" style=""><svg version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
data-hasqtip="7" viewBox="0 0 718 130" style="overflow: hidden; position: 
relative; left: 0px;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">Created with Raphaël 2.2.0</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><circle cx="493.62499999999994" cy="73.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#87ceeb" stroke="#87ceeb" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">Assessment</title></circle><circle cx="508.5833333333333" cy="73.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#87ceeb" stroke="#87ceeb" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">...</title></circle><circle cx="519.2678571428571" cy="73.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#87ceeb" stroke="#87ceeb" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">...</title></circle><circle cx="534.2261904761905" cy="73.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#00ffff" stroke="#00ffff" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">Collateral</title></circle><circle cx="549.1845238095237" cy="73.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">...</title></circle><circle cx="564.1428571428571" cy="73.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">...</title></circle><circle cx="579.1011904761905" cy="73.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#87ceeb" stroke="#87ceeb" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">...</title></circle><circle cx="534.2261904761905" cy="64.5" r="2.5" 
fill="#006400" stroke="#006400" stroke-width="2" class="chronoline-event" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><title 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Plan Dev - 
MHS</title></circle><path fill="none" stroke="#b8b8b8" d="M0,80L718,80" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><text x="15" 
y="118" text-anchor="middle" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" 
stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; 
font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan dy="3.5" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">2017</tspan></text><path 
fill="none" stroke="#b8b8b8" d="M-36.32738095238095,80L-36.32738095238095,84" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><text 
x="-36.32738095238095" y="94" text-anchor="middle" 
font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; 
font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;"><tspan dy="3.5" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">01</tspan></text><text 
x="15" y="106" text-anchor="middle" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" 
font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" font-weight="bold" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; 
font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;"><tspan dy="3.5" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">JAN</tspan></text><path 
fill="none" stroke="#b8b8b8" d="M-6.410714285714286,80L-6.410714285714286,84" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><text 
x="-6.410714285714286" y="94" text-anchor="middle" 
font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; 
font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;"><tspan dy="3.5" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">15</tspan></text><path 
fill="none" stroke="#b8b8b8" d="M29.916666666666664,80L29.916666666666664,84" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><text 
x="29.916666666666664" y="94" text-anchor="middle" 
font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; 
font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;"><tspan dy="3.5" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">01</tspan></text><text 
x="29.916666666666664" y="106" text-anchor="middle" 
font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" 
font-weight="bold" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: 
bold;"><tspan dy="3.5" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">FEB</tspan></text><path fill="none" stroke="#b8b8b8" 
d="M59.83333333333333,80L59.83333333333333,84" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>
<text 
x="707.3154761904761" y="94" text-anchor="middle" 
font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; 
font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;"><tspan dy="3.5" 
style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0);">15</tspan></text></svg>
</div><div class="chronoline-left" 
style="margin-top: 40px; height: 40px; display: none;"><div 
class="chronoline-left-icon" style="margin-top: 12.5px;"></div></div><div 
class="chronoline-right" style="margin-top: 40px; height: 40px; display: 
none;"><div class="chronoline-right-icon" style="margin-top: 
12.5px;"></div></div></div></div>
```

[svg ELEMENT IN CHROME/FF USING viewBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7OCb.png)

[svg ELEMENT IN PHANTOMJS USING same viewBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q3iV.png)

Comment: To help you, we need to see the html enclosing the svg element and all relevant CSS for screen and print media.

Comment: Thanks ccprog for any help/heads up you could provide

Comment: Look like a [known bug](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11956)

Comment: Thank you sir! Amazed that I missed that after all that googling :(